# WebApi: mistmatch between ids

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi

Given the following route

```
/api/Person/15
```

And we do a PUT to this route with the body:

```
{
    id: 8,
    name: 'Joosh'
}
```

The route segment value is `15` but the `[FromBody]` id is `8`.

Right now there is something like the following in our controllers:

```cs
public Model Put(string id, [FromBody] Model model)
{
     if (id != model.Id)
         throw new Exception("Id mismatch!");

     // ... Do normal stuff
}
```

Is there a "default" or DRY-ish method for doing this without assuming that it will always be as simple as parameter ID and Model.Id property?

Comment: Why do you even allow `Id` property in body?

Comment: To avoid creating GET / PUT / POST models that are identical except that GET contains an ID and PUT/POST do not?

Comment: Usually its only matter of time till they start to differ more and more, nonetheless you might consider creating "update model" and then create derived type with `Id` property only.

Comment: Instead of `throw` you should `return BadRequest("Id missmatch!");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve via custom model validation

```
[HttpPut("api/Person/{id}")]
public IActionResult Put(string id, [FromBody]Person person)
{
    // ... Do normal stuff
    return Ok();
}


public class Person
{
    [ValidateId]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

}


public sealed class ValidateId : ValidationAttribute
{
    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object id, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        var httpContextAccessor = (IHttpContextAccessor)validationContext.GetService(typeof(IHttpContextAccessor));
        var routeData = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.GetRouteData();
        var idFromUrl = routeData.Values["id"];

        if (id.Equals(idFromUrl))
        {
            return ValidationResult.Success;
        }
        else
        {
            return new ValidationResult("Id mismatch!");
        }
    }
}


// In the Startup class add the IHttpContextAccessor

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // ...
    services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a "default" or DRY-ish method for doing this without assuming that it will always be as simple as parameter ID and Model.Id property?

Custom validation logic can be implemented in an ActionFilter. Because the ActionFilter is processed after the model binding in the action execution, the model and action parameters can be used in an ActionFilter without having to read from the Request Body, or the URL. You could refer to the below working demo:

- Customize ValidationFilter

  ```
  public class ValidationFilter: ActionFilterAttribute
  {
   private readonly ILogger _logger;

  public ValidationFilter(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
  {
      _logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger("ValidatePayloadTypeFilter");
  }

  public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
  {
      var carDto = context.ActionArguments["car"] as Car;

      var id = context.ActionArguments["id"];
      if (Convert.ToInt32(id)!=carDto.Id)
      {
          context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 400;
          context.Result = new ContentResult()
          {
              Content = "Id mismatch!"
          };
          return;
      }

      base.OnActionExecuting(context);
   }
  }
  ```
- Register this action filter in the ConfigureServices method

  ```
  services.AddScoped<ValidationFilter>();
  ```
- Call this action filter as a service

  ```
  public class Car
  {
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public string CarName { get; set; }
  }

  [ServiceFilter(typeof(ValidationFilter))]
  [HttpPut("{id}")]
  public Car Put(int id, [FromBody] Car car)
  {
   // the stuff you want
  }
  ```

Reference:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-2.2#action-filters

https://code-maze.com/action-filters-aspnetcore/#comments

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own CustomValidation and compare the values of id and model.id. 
Check this link 
[example of custom model validation](https://dzone.com/articles/creating-your-own-validation-attribute-in-mvc-and).